# IE6-7 Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, igoogle

I am using the "mimic igoogle tutorial with cookies" by James Padolsey
http://james.padolsey.com/tag/cookies/

I have encountered a problem with the way that IE6 & 7 interprets the javascript. I have found the problem but I have no way of working around it.

The following code is long but the problem is only in one small section

```
/*
 * Script from NETTUTS.com [by James Padolsey] V.2 (ENHANCED, WITH COOKIES!!!)
 * @requires jQuery($), jQuery UI & sortable/draggable UI modules & jQuery COOKIE plugin
 */

var iNettuts = {

    jQuery : $,

    settings : {
        columns : '.column',
        widgetSelector: '.widget',
        handleSelector: '.widget-head',
        contentSelector: '.widget-content',

        /* If you don't want preferences to be saved change this value to false, otherwise change it to the name of the cookie: */
        saveToCookie: false,

        widgetDefault : {
            movable: true,
            removable: true,
            collapsible: true,
            editable: false,
            colorClasses : ['color-yellow', 'color-red', 'color-blue', 'color-white', 'color-orange', 'color-green']
        },
        widgetIndividual : {
            static: {
                movable: false,
                removable: true,
                collapsible: true,
                editable: false,
            }
        },
    },

    init : function () {
        this.attachStylesheet('css/sortable.js.css');
        this.sortWidgets();
        this.addWidgetControls();
        this.makeSortable();
    },

    getWidgetSettings : function (id) {
        var $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings;
        return (id&&settings.widgetIndividual[id]) ? $.extend({},settings.widgetDefault,settings.widgetIndividual[id]) : settings.widgetDefault;
    },

    addWidgetControls : function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings;

        $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
            var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id);
            if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
                $('<a href="#" class="remove tooltip" title="Close this window">&nbsp;</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    /* STOP event bubbling */
                    e.stopPropagation();    
                }).click(function () {

                    if(confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
                        $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                            opacity: 0    
                        },function () {
                            $(this).slideUp(function () {
                                $(this).toggleClass('closed');
                                                                /* Save prefs to cookie: */
                                iNettuts.savePreferences();
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
            }

            if (thisWidgetSettings.editable) {
                $('<a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    /* STOP event bubbling */
                    e.stopPropagation();    
                }).toggle(function () {
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-66px 0', width: '55px'})
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find('.edit-box').show().find('input').focus();
                    return false;
                },function () {
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '', width: '20px'})
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find('.edit-box').hide();
                    return false;
                }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector,this));
                $('<div class="edit-box" style="display:none;"/>')
                    .append('<ul><li class="item"><label>Change the title?</label><input value="' + $('h3',this).text() + '"/></li>')
                    .append((function(){
                        var colorList = '<li class="item"><label>Available colors:</label><ul class="colors">';
                        $(thisWidgetSettings.colorClasses).each(function () {
                            colorList += '<li class="' + this + '"/>';
                        });
                        return colorList + '</ul>';
                    })())
                    .append('</ul>')
                    .insertAfter($(settings.handleSelector,this));
            }

            if (thisWidgetSettings.collapsible) {
                $('<a href="#" class="collapse tooltip" title="Show / hide this window">&nbsp;</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    /* STOP event bubbling */
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }).click(function(){

                    $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).toggleClass('collapsed');
                    /* Save prefs to cookie: */
                    iNettuts.savePreferences();
                    return false;
                }).prependTo($(settings.handleSelector,this));
            }
        });

        $('.edit-box').each(function () {
            $('input',this).keyup(function () {
                $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).find('h3').text( $(this).val().length>20 ? $(this).val().substr(0,20)+'...' : $(this).val() );
                iNettuts.savePreferences();
            });
            $('ul.colors li',this).click(function () {

                var colorStylePattern = /\bcolor-[\w]{1,}\b/,
                    thisWidgetColorClass = $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).attr('class').match(colorStylePattern)
                if (thisWidgetColorClass) {
                    $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                        .removeClass(thisWidgetColorClass[0])
                        .addClass($(this).attr('class').match(colorStylePattern)[0]);
                    /* Save prefs to cookie: */
                    iNettuts.savePreferences();
                }
                return false;

            });
        });

    },

    attachStylesheet : function (href) {
        var $ = this.jQuery;
        return $('<link href="' + href + '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').appendTo('head');
    },

    makeSortable : function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings,
            $sortableItems = (function () {
                var notSortable = null;
                $(settings.widgetSelector,$(settings.columns)).each(function (i) {
                    if (!iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id).movable) {
                        if(!this.id) {
                            this.id = 'widget-no-id-' + i;
                        }
                        notSortable += '#' + this.id + ',';
                    }
                });
                return $('> li:not(' + notSortable + ')', settings.columns);
            })();

        $sortableItems.find(settings.handleSelector).css({
            cursor: 'move'
        }).mousedown(function (e) {
            $sortableItems.css({width:''});
            $(this).parent().css({
                width: $(this).parent().width() + 'px'
            });
        }).mouseup(function () {
            if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('dragging')) {
                $(this).parent().css({width:''});
            } else {
                $(settings.columns).sortable('disable');
            }
        });

        $(settings.columns).sortable({
            items: $sortableItems,
            connectWith: $(settings.columns),
            handle: settings.handleSelector,
            placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            revert: 300,
            delay: 100,
            opacity: 0.8,
            containment: 'document',
            start: function (e,ui) {
                $(ui.helper).addClass('dragging');
            },
            stop: function (e,ui) {
                $(ui.item).css({width:''}).removeClass('dragging');
                $(settings.columns).sortable('enable');
                /* Save prefs to cookie: */
                iNettuts.savePreferences();
            }
        });
    },

    savePreferences : function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings,
            cookieString = '';

        if(!settings.saveToCookie) {return;}

        /* Assemble the cookie string */
        $(settings.columns).each(function(i){
            cookieString += (i===0) ? '' : '|';
            $(settings.widgetSelector,this).each(function(i){
                cookieString += (i===0) ? '' : ';';
                /* ID of widget: */
                cookieString += $(this).attr('id') + ',';
                /* Color of widget (color classes) */
                cookieString += $(this).attr('class').match(/\bcolor-[\w]{1,}\b/) + ',';
                /* Title of widget (replaced used characters) */
                cookieString += $('h3:eq(0)',this).text().replace(/\|/g,'[-PIPE-]').replace(/,/g,'[-COMMA-]') + ',';
                /* Collapsed/not collapsed widget? : */
                cookieString += $(settings.contentSelector,this).css('display') === 'none' ? 'collapsed,' : 'not-collapsed,';                
                /* Closed/not closed widget? : */
                cookieString += $(settings.handleSelector,this).css('display') === 'none' ? 'closed' : 'not-closed';
            });
        });
        $.cookie(settings.saveToCookie,cookieString,{
            expires: 10
            //path: '/'
        });
    },

    sortWidgets : function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings;

        /* Read cookie: */
        var cookie = $.cookie(settings.saveToCookie);
        if(!settings.saveToCookie||!cookie) {
            /* Get rid of loading gif and show columns: */
            $('body').css({background:'#fff'});
            $(settings.columns).css({visibility:'visible'});
            return;
        }

        /* For each column */
        $(settings.columns).each(function(i){

            var thisColumn = $(this),
                widgetData = cookie.split('|')[i].split(';');

            $(widgetData).each(function(){
                if(!this.length) {return;}
                var thisWidgetData = this.split(','),
                    clonedWidget = $('#' + thisWidgetData[0]),
                    colorStylePattern = /\bcolor-[\w]{1,}\b/,
                    thisWidgetColorClass = $(clonedWidget).attr('class').match(colorStylePattern);

                /* Add/Replace new colour class: */
                if (thisWidgetColorClass) {
                    $(clonedWidget).removeClass(thisWidgetColorClass[0]).addClass(thisWidgetData[1]);
                }

                /* Add/replace new title (Bring back reserved characters): */
                $(clonedWidget).find('h3:eq(0)').html(thisWidgetData[2].replace(/\[-PIPE-\]/g,'|').replace(/\[-COMMA-\]/g,','));

                /* Modify collapsed state if needed: */
                if(thisWidgetData[3]==='collapsed') {
                    /* Set CSS styles so widget is in COLLAPSED state */
                    $(clonedWidget).addClass('collapsed');
                }

                /* Modify closed state if needed: */                
                if(thisWidgetData[4]==='closed') {
                    /* Set CSS styles so widget is in CLOSED state */
                    $(clonedWidget).addClass('closed');
                }

                $('#' + thisWidgetData[0]).remove();
                $(thisColumn).append(clonedWidget);
            });
        });

        /* All done, remove loading gif and show columns: */
        $('body').css({background:'#fff'});
        $(settings.columns).css({visibility:'visible'});
    }

};

iNettuts.init();
```

If I leave this section blank

```
widgetIndividual : {
    static: {
        movable: false,
        removable: true,
        collapsible: true,
        editable: false,
    }
}
```

For example, like this

```
widgetIndividual : {

    }
```

Then it works fine on all browsers, unfortunately I need to use the Individual Widget settings for my project.

IE6-7 throws out an error because of these guys "}", I have no idea why.

Comment: As ShankarSangoli says, there is a syntax error. The code will fail in many browsers other than IE 6 and 7. The trailing comma has been allowed in ES5, but not all browsers are up to speed with that yet.

Comment: @RobG - The trailing comma error comes in IE only browsers rest all browsers are happy with it.

Comment: "AlL" other browsers? Which ones did you test? It is specifically a syntax error in ES3, though some browsers tolerated it. There are many browsers still in use that will not allow it. I can't remember which ones because I haven't tripped that error in many years, but it used to be all of them (up to Firefox and Safari 2 at least).

Comment: Thanks guys, Shankar solved it. The problem was only evident in IE6-7. Opera, Safari, FF3.5 - FF4, Chrome, CHrome Canary and IE8-9 all tested fine. Thanks everyone for the feedback. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the last comma in this object it will work.

```
    widgetIndividual : {
        static: {
            movable: false,
            removable: true,
            collapsible: true,
            editable: false
        }
}
```