# Small syntax problem

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this piece of code?

I can't seem to make the two functions together work when I call the variable... They do work separately however...

```
var ficheHandler = {
   animateFiche: function(fiche) {
      fiche
         .css('visibility','visible');
         .animate({"opacity" : 1,}, 150, function() {
          });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extraneous `;` at the end of `.css('visibility','visible');` which breaks the statement before `.animate...`.  Remove it and you should be good to go.

I would also remove the last `,` in `{"opacity" : 1,}` since that will break on [IE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811720/ie6-7-javascript-problem/6811731#6811731).

Comment: There's also an unnecessary comma after the 1. Should be {"opacity" : 1}.

Comment: @TJ, Thanks.  I noticed that just after I submitted.  I edited to include a reference to that and to a thread with discussion of it.